# Regular expression to find content in braces

Tags: javascript, regex

I have string like "abcdefecg asdasda(SIAD) (EA91)" what i need is to get EA91.

I use regular expression to get content in parens but this give me only first existence.

```
var regExpTextBetweenBraces = /\(([^)]+)\)/;
var res = "abcdefecg asdasda (SIAD) (EA91)".match(regExpTextBetweenBraces);
```

res[1] will contain SIAD, but i need EA91. How can i do this. Any help ?

Comment: Do you mean braces `{}` or parens `()`?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try `/\([^)]+\).*?\(([^)]+)\)/` It'll look for a `(something) (Matched)` all you needed to do was to tell it to not match the first brace. Or you could use a global match and use an index.

Comment: it is not valid regex

Comment: Sorry I didn't have the forward slash.

Answer (score 4):

Just use the global `g` flag on your regex:

```
var regExpTextBetweenBraces = /\(([^)]+)\)/g;
```